# How do I remove entries in a tuple with duplicated properties?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, tuples

I have a tuple dictionary consisting of three attributes: Name, Address, Phone.

Example:

- Johnny Tarr, 1234 Gaelic Way, 555-402-9687
- Patrick Murphy, 1234 Taylor Road, 555-555-5555
- Patrick Murphy, 1234 Morrison Court, 555-555-5555

How do I remove the entries where two of the three properties are duplicated?

**A failed attempt to iterate the collection:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < fileList.Count; j++)
    {
        // Test Results: There are supposed to be 362 duplicates. Outputting only 225 entries. A mix of duplicates and not duplicates.
        if (fileList[i].Item1.Equals(fileList[j].Item1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && fileList[i].Item3.Equals(fileList[j].Item3, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            file.WriteLine(fileList[i].Item1 + "|" + fileList[i].Item2 + "|" + fileList[i].Item3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code and what you tried so far.

Comment: You'll need to provide sample input/desired output. Cut down you "362-duplicates" file to a few entries, just enough to reproduce the problem. Also, the address doesn't matter here, right (never duplicate)? This seems clear from your code but not from the question.

Comment: Eventually, the desired output will be just the Johnny Tarr entry, but currently, the desired output is only the two Patrick Murphy entries. I'll see about paring down the test suite. And, yes, the address doesn't matter. Will update later after long rest!

Comment: Well, of course it is. You only write  the duplicate entries in your code and leave the others alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var distincts = fileList.GroupBy(t => t.Item1 + "," + t.Item3)
                        .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                        .Select(g => g.Single());

foreach (var item in distincts)
{
  Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

This groups your tuples by Name/Phone, then keeps only groups that contain single tuples, and then selects that single tuple for the output list of distinct tuples.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly, removing 360 duplicates from the results, which I verified with Excel filtering. (The previous number, 362, was inaccurate.) I also understand Linq queries much better, too. I had no idea what the letters meant before.